# Copy sheet with protected cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, cells, protected

I have an excel worksheet that I protected certain cells with a password. AM afraid it could be touched by another person. How would it be done to COPY A SHEET TO A NEW FILE AND RETAIN THE PROTECTED CELLS WITH PASSWORD?

Comment: Are you using the normal Excel review > Protect feature or something else? (I am slightly puzzled by your "command-line" tag)

Comment: If you use the features in Protect group, I suggest you after copying, please protect the new sheet again.

Answer (score 0):

If you "protect" a sheet in Excel and use a password when you do that, this protection will follow the sheet if it is later copied or moved to another workbook. You don't need to do anything more.